# Unix while loop

Tags: unix, while-loop

I have to create a while loop using the following information.

```
Clive Cussler,Ghost Ship,9780399167317
Clive Cussler,Bootlegger,9780399167294
James Patterson,Invisible,9780316405348
James Patterson,Gone,9781455515844
James Rollins,Map of Bones,9780062017857
Michael Connelly,The Lincoln Lawyer,9781455516346
David Baldacci, The Escape,9781478984344
```

The script must seprate them by author, name of book and isbn. To look like this

```
Author                Name of Book                   ISBN
Clive Cussler         Ghost Ship                     978-0399-16731-7
Clive Cussler         Bootlegger                     978-0399-16729-4
James Patterson       Invisible                      978-0316-40534-8
James Patterson       Gone                           978-1455-51584-4
James Rollins         Map of Bones                   978-0062-01785-7
Michael Connelly      The Lincoln Lawyer             978-1455-51634-6
David Baldacci        The Escape                     978-1478-98434-4
```

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: The first thing to decide is which language you want to use.  Bash shell scripting?  Perl?  C?  C++?  Python?  awk?  sed?

Comment: Yes, you have to decide the language you want to use... ;-)

Comment: And then try to write it, and if you hit a problem, *then* it is appropriate to post your question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

using python:

```
f=open('file.txt')
print("{:<30}{:<30}{:<30}".format("Author","Name Of Book","ISBN"))
for x in f:
    x = x.strip().split(',')
    print("{:<30}{:<30}{:<30}".format(x[0],x[1],x[2]))
```

using awk:

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{printf("%-30s%-30s%-30s\n","Author","Name of Book","ISBN")}{printf("%-30s%-30s%-30s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' file.txt
```

output:

```
Author                        Name Of Book                  ISBN                          
Clive Cussler                 Ghost Ship                    9780399167317                 
Clive Cussler                 Bootlegger                    9780399167294                 
James Patterson               Invisible                     9780316405348                 
James Patterson               Gone                          9781455515844                 
James Rollins                 Map of Bones                  9780062017857                 
Michael Connelly              The Lincoln Lawyer            9781455516346                 
David Baldacci                 The Escape                   9781478984344
```